# How do I check if a variable is type list if I already have list defined as a variable (in Decipher/Forsta survey building platform)?

Tags: python, survey, shadowing

The platform I am working on, unfortunately, forced me to have "list" defined as a variable name.  Additionally, type is a variable name that is built in.  Pretty bad oversight considering the server-side language used in this system is Python!  I have need of determining whether a variable is of type list.  Normally, I would obviously use

`isinstance(q, list)`

or

`type(q) == list`

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT FROM SEPT 2023:

I realized that I gave too little information, so I came back to clarify, in case this comes up for anyone else, and make the question more useful for others.  The software this is a problem is in a survey programming platform called Decipher/FocusVision (now Forsta).  It's wonderful and powerful overall.  It's built on Python 3.x, but a restricted environment which uses Python 2.x is what is made available for a survey programmer to use within a survey they're building.  And, unfortunately, both `list` and `type` are assigned as global variables, so are overridden within the survey.

Therefore, all of these solutions do not work:

```
isinstance(var, list)
type(var) == list
type(var) == type([]) (I accepted the second answer because I hadn't provided this information and it correctly answered the question as stated)
```

For anyone who uses Decipher and runs into this, what I had to do was make use of the hooks system and make a global function available within all surveys, as the hooks system exists outside of the restricted survey environment:

embedded.py:

```
def type_as_str(var):
    """ This function returns the variable type (class) as a string, or 'unknown' 
    if an exception occurs attempting this (to ensure that a str is always returned).
    This is necessary because of Decipher's restricted environment overriding both 
    'list' and 'type'.  'isinstance' can be used for most data types, but this
    function provides a means of identifying data type that works in all scenarios. """

    try:
        return type(var).__name__
    except:
        return 'unknown'
```

hooks.py:

```
def survey_environment(env, survey):
    """ This hook function is executed every time someone takes a survey, and allows you to modify 
    the survey and its environment. """
    
    #
    # Loading globals into an object e, which will contain everything run in embedded.py once done.  
    # Globals will be able to be used in embedded.py This allows us to make some of the global 
    # variables and functions available within embedded.py.
    #
    e = {}
    e['allQuestions'] = env['allQuestions']
    e['decLang'] = env['decLang']
    e['res'] = env['res']
    e['setMarker'] = env['setMarker']
    e['gv'] = env['gv']

    #
    # Executing embedded.py with globals loaded into e.  This allows us to then add the variables 
    # and functions from that file into the survey's environment, creating global functions/etc
    # that are available in every survey without having to hard-code them into the surveys,
    # and with a greater range of functionality, since the hooks system is not run in the restricted
    # environment that surveys are.
    #
    execfile('selfserve/53b/embedded.py', e)
    
    #
    # Storing functions from embedded.py's environment into the survey's
    #
    env['load_zip_code_db_file'] = e['load_zip_code_db_file']
    # In our environment, we have 73 different items loaded from embedded.py, it's incredibly useful
```

Then in a survey, you can use the function like so:

```
if type_as_str(some_list_var) == 'list':
    #do something
```

Or in any other way you might want to.  And not only with list type, but any type at all.

I know many companies use Decipher/Forsta software in the market research industry, so I hope this updated question and self-answer helps someone.

Comment: `type(a) == type([])`

Comment: `isinstance(q, [].__class__)`.  Assuming that this insane platform you're using doesn't suddenly decide to define `isinstance` as a variable...

Comment: that doesn't work.  It says "__class__ is an invalid attribute name because it starts with _"

Comment: *What*, exactly, says `__class__` is an invalid attribute name?

Comment: Sorry for the super late response.  The software I was building inside of says that.  It runs a limited version of Python that is supposed to prevent "unsafe code", and doesn't let you reference any attributes that start with an underscore.  Anyway I've come a LONG way since then, and figured this out many moons ago!  Thanks for your reply, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in names are also available via the `builtins` module, should you shadow the name.

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.list is list
True
>>> list = 3
>>> builtins.list is list
False
>>> builtins.list("abc")
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> del list
>>> builtins.list is list
True
```

The module is also available without explicitly importing it using the built-in name `__builtins__`.

Comment: Thank you!  THis is very useful, and something I didn't know.  Since I posted this quewstion, I've moved into software devel;opment at my company, and recently, into lead developer.  Taught myself Django, and we have v1.4.1 of our web platform in production.  I've learned so, so much since this post was made, but you still learn something new every day in coding!  Or in my case, 10+ new things most days.

I've changed this to the accepted answer, as it solves the problem better (in fact the previously accepted answer does not, but I thought it did without some information I learned since)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make the comparison by

```
type(q) == type([])
```

Comment: Thank you.  I marked this as the accepted answer because it correctly answers the question I asked (can't use "list" as a var or function)

Unfortunately (and insanely), they also do not allow the usage of "type"!  The software is a survey programming platform.  Python 2.7 is run in a restricted environment within the surveys, and is used to perform calculations and other functions on the server side.  The reason they use a restricted environment makes sense, but it makes no sense to me why they would have had built-in variables already assigned to both "list" and "type".