# How to get access to a type symbol in a function that shadows it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say that I have a function like:

```
def foo(int):
    ...
```

How can I get access to the an instance of the meta-type of ints (or indeed any other type that is shadowed) inside that function?

Of course in this particular function I can do `type(<int instance>)` and get that but what about the general case where I cannot create an instance of the type easily?

Comment: Assume that shadowing is a constraint.

Comment: In this case it's not up to me to change the name. If you need a concrete reason why this would happen see https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/issues/337

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of a question that explains how to get access to a shadowed `builtins` symbol. Even though I used `int` as an example for this question, the question is about how to get access to the type object of a type in the general case and this is not covered by the linked question.

Comment: Might not be generally possible, at least not without awful hacks, especially if you're so restricted that you can't even change a bad parameter name.

Comment: What do you mean by "meta-type"?

Comment: By `def foo(int)`, do you mean that the *name* of the parameter is `int` or that the *type* of the parameter is `int`?

Comment: I mean that the parameter is named `int` so I cannot access the type `int` trivially from within the body of the function.

Comment: Ah, I see. And you mean it's not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597207/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-type-list-if-i-already-have-list-defined-as-a-va because you also want to look in the globals, not only in the built-ins?

Comment: @mkrieger1, yes

Comment: @namesis Wait, only builtins and globals, so not truly "the general case"?

Comment: @mkrieger1, maybe 'meta-type' is not the best terminology but I was referring to an object of type `<class 'type'>` that refers to ints. So effectively what you get by `type(2)`.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that the type can only be defined in `__builtins__` or is an import in the global namespace it may be possible to retrieve it with a function like:

```
def get_global(name):
    if name in globals():
        return globals()[name]
    if hasattr(__builtins__, name):
        return getattr(__builtins__, name)
    return None
```

```
from pandas import DataFrame
print(get_global("DataFrame"))
print(get_global("int"))
```

which gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work.

Comment: `int` is not a **global** variable, it is a **built-in** variable. (In other words, it's not in the current module, but in the `builtins` module)

Comment: @MechanicPig, oh, indeed, you are right! I only tested it with imported types earlier.